# Android How to iterate an R.drawable object

Tags: android, for-loop, drawable

I'm trying to display a frame by frame animation and want to iterate through the drawables so I don't have to type all their names in case the number of frames increases.

However I can't seem to find how to iterate through the drawables. I have looked up a fair bit of java for loop tutorials but they all just printed stuff which (as far as I'm sure) don't have to use here.

Here's the relevant code (the image's names are dude1, dude2, ...):

```
   private void startAnimation(){
       animation = new AnimationDrawable();
       for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
           animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dude(i)), 100);
       }
       animation.setOneShot(true);

       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, 90);
       params.alignWithParent = true;
       params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);      
       imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
       imageView.setImageDrawable(animation);
       imageView.post(new Starter());
   }
```

Thx!

Comment: What's in the starter Runnable?

Comment: You can use getIdentifier() method to get id for drawable.

Answer (score 6):

I think the last answer is varely true but it may be:

```
for (int i=0; i <10;i++){
      animation.addFrame(
         getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("dude" + i,"drawable",
             getPackageName()),100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  `getResources()` needs a context.

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getIdentifier("dude" + i,"drawable", getPackageName()),100);
}
```

Here, I have assumed 10 frames (i<10).

Comment: This gives me the next error:
The method addFrame(Drawable, int) in the type AnimationDrawable is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)

Answer (score 1):

I have used **Simon**'s answer to iterate through my drawables that are named "c1" through "c54" and placed in an array.  Here is the code I just used that works for me.

```
 private void getDeckDrawables() {
    for (int i=1; i<53; i++){
        intArrDeck[i-1] = getResources().getIdentifier("c"+i,"drawable",getPackageName());
    }
}
```

Previously, I typed them manually which took up too much room for my taste.

```
private void getDeckDrawables() {
    intArrDeck[0]=R.drawable.c1;
    intArrDeck[1]=R.drawable.c2;
    intArrDeck[2]=R.drawable.c3;
}
```